# Prove: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}e^{-\pi x}}{\cosh\frac{3x\zeta(2)}{20}} dx = 10$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I want to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}e^{-\pi x}}{\cosh\frac{3x\zeta(2)}{20}} dx = 10$$

Have not tried it yet, but it may be tough. All I know is that  ζ(2) is  π²/6. I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure of the bounds of integration?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai I've misspelled bounds of integration, sorry! Just corrected it :)

Comment: Do you need a full solution? Or just a bit of help?

Comment: @sos440 I need a full solution. thanks!

Comment: $$\tan^{-1}(e^{-\pi x}) + \tan^{-1}(e^{\pi x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the integral 
\begin{align}
I(a,b)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan e^{-ax}}{\cosh b x}dx=\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan e^{-ax}}{\cosh b x}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan e^{ax}}{\cosh b x}dx=\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\cosh b x}=\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4b}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\cosh  x}=\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{4b}.
\end{align}
Now set $\displaystyle b=\frac{3\zeta(2)}{20}=\frac{\pi^2}{40}$.